Changing from file_get_contents to curl
I've been using file_get_contents in php until the last month when it's stopped working. So I've tried using curl but I'm now getting errors when I extract data from the downloaded webpage (finance.yahoo.com).
This is my code (section):
    $sym = $symbol;
    $yahooURL="https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/$sym/history";
//  get stock name
//  $data = file_get_contents($yahooURL);

    $curl_handle=curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $yahooURL);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       
    $data = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
        // extract page title and put it in $name
    $title = preg_match('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/ims', $data, $matches) ? $matches[0] :   null;
    $title = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9]\.* \; /','',$title);   //line 124
    $title = preg_replace('/ Stock \- Yahoo Finance/','-',$title);
    $name = "$title";

I now get an error message: Deprecated: preg_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated in /home/cappleby/portfolio.cappleby.net.au/includes/helpers.php on line 124.
Im struggling with the preg_match and preg_replace code. I'd love some help please.
An extract of a sample $data is:
<title>ANZ Group Holdings Limited (ANZ.AX) Stock Historical Prices &amp; Data - Yahoo Finance</title>
I've tried a number of permutations of the extraction code without success. When I dump $title to the screen it comes out blank. If I return the $data to the calling procedure it loads yahoo.com but not the page I've put in. If I download $data the information is all there.
I should add that I'm using simple_html_dom_parser to extract the contents of the table that comes later in the page but I couldn't see how to use that to extract the page title.

Do the preg_replace only if $title is not null. Moreover, don't parse HTML with regex, use a parser.

My problem is that $title should not be null - see the sample data above? Any suggestions about how the simple Dom parser wil get me the same data?

Are you sure $data contains what you think? Did you print it before calling preg_match?

Thank you for your help. I've now managed to do it using the Dom parser: foreach($x->query('//title') as $title){
$names[$i] = $title -> textContent." ";
$i++;
}
$name = $names[0];

And I'm back again. Having supposedly fixed the problem and having the program working smothly for a couple of days, I'm now back to getting an error saying the title element is empty. I've again checked the html I'm reading and nothing has changed.

The problem appears to have been that Yahoo requires a referer element in the cURL stream. Once I put in my domain url it began working again.

If it works, you could answer (with details) your own question.

This is how my code ended up. $symbol is the share price symbol:
    $sym = $symbol;
    $yahooURL="https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/$sym/history";
// get stock name
// get price data - use simple_html_dom.php (added to /include) 

    $base = $yahooURL;
// use cURL to download contents of te web page with share price history on it.
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
// Yahoo appears to require a referer page to use cURL
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, https://www.mywebsite.net.au/);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $page = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

 $dom = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML($page);
    libxml_clear_errors();


$x = new DOMXpath($dom);
$i = 0;

//Extract title of page - company name 
foreach($x->query('//title') as $title){
    $names[$i] = $title -> textContent." ";
    $i++;
    }
$name = $names[0];
$name = preg_replace('/ stock(.*?) Yahoo Finance/','',$name);

//Extract the last day's price details and put in array for analysis later
$i = 0;
foreach($x->query('//td') as $td){
    $elements[$i] = $td -> textContent." ";
    $i++;
    }

